# scdaemon.conf missing from gpg directory

Tags: linux, gpg, smartcard

I tried to setup gpg for use with a smartcard, but the instructions specified edits to `scdaemon.conf`, which for some reason is missing from the `.gnupg` folder in the home directory. The folder does contain other files, and gpg seems to be working correctly. Using `find` to look for `scdaemon.conf` turned up nothing, reinstalling `gpg` and `scdaemon` didn't resolve the issue. Does anyone know what the issue might be? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply create the file. `touch ~/.gpg/scdaemon conf;chmod 640 ~/.gpg/scdaemon.conf`

Also, check and re-check that you followed the instructions.

Comment: Does gpg automatically initialise scdaemon.conf? The file is still empty.